# Access denied exception while creating sub site in a SharePoint site collection using SharePoint web service

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a following requirement

Requirement : "Create Site collection programatically on a web application which is hosted on a remote server and then create Sub site in it"

I am able to successfully create Site collection using Admin.asmx web service. But, for Sub sit when i use following code - it throws an exception "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

```
Uri site = new Uri("http://SharePoint2010Site/"); 
string webServicePath = "_vti_bin/Sites.asmx";
string webServiceUrl = Path.Combine(site.AbsoluteUri, webServicePath);

Sites webService = new Sites();
webService.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
webService.Url = webServiceUrl;

//the following line creates the sub site
string result = webService.CreateWeb("Sub Site", "Sub Site", "Sub Site Desc", "STS#0", 
    1033, true, 1033, true, 1033, true, true, true, true, true, true, true);
```

What can be the reason for Access denied exception?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you made yourself the owner of the site collection.

What parameters did you pass to the site collection create?

Comment: Yes, i am sure about that. Parameters i passed to it was adminService.CreateSite("http://SharePoint2010Site/sites/sitecollectionname",
"Title", "Description", 1033, "STS#0",
userloginname, userloginname,
useremail, "", "");

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you want to access remote site, try passing UserName, Password and Domain name as shown below.

```
webService.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName Here", "Password Here", "Domain Name Here");
```

Comment: Credentials on the other server was same, so i had used default credentials.But even by specifying the credentials explicitly using NetworCredentials i still get the same access denied exception.

Comment: Did you specified domain name also, or pass it as string.empty

Comment: Yes, I had specified actual domain name.

Comment: try following steps given on this link: http://aarohblah.blogspot.com/2009/07/access-is-denied-exception-from-hresult.html

Comment: looks like the link you specified is down !!